# vectorize for-loop to fill Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

For a financial application, I'm trying to create a DataFrame where each row is a session date value for a particular equity. To get the data, I'm using [Pandas Remote Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html). So, for example, the features I'm trying to create might be the adjusted closes for the preceding 32 sessions.

This is easy to do in a for-loop, but it takes quite a long time for large features sets (like going back to 1960 on "ge" and making each row contain the preceding 256 session values). Does anyone see a good way to vectorize this code?

```
import pandas as pd

def featurize(equity_data, n_sessions, col_label='Adj Close'):
    """ 
    Generate a raw (unnormalized) feature set from the input data.
    The value at col_label on the given date is taken
    as a feature, and each row contains values for n_sessions
    """
    features = pd.DataFrame(index=equity_data.index[(n_sessions - 1):],
            columns=range((-n_sessions + 1), 1)) 
    for i in range(len(features.index)):
        features.iloc[i, :] = equity_data[i:(n_sessions + i)][col_label].values
    return features
```

I could alternatively just multi-thread this easily, but I'm guessing that pandas does that automatically if I can vectorize it. I mention that mainly because my primary concern is performance. So, if multi-threading is likely to outperform vectorization in any significant way, then I'd prefer that.

Short example of input and output:

`>>> eq_data
             Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date

2014-01-02  15.42  15.45  15.28  15.44  31528500      14.96
2014-01-03  15.52  15.64  15.30  15.51  46122300      15.02
2014-01-06  15.72  15.76  15.52  15.58  42657600      15.09
2014-01-07  15.73  15.74  15.35  15.38  54476300      14.90
2014-01-08  15.60  15.71  15.51  15.54  48448300      15.05
2014-01-09  15.83  16.02  15.77  15.84  67836500      15.34
2014-01-10  16.01  16.11  15.94  16.07  44984000      15.57
2014-01-13  16.37  16.53  16.08  16.11  57566400      15.61
2014-01-14  16.31  16.43  16.17  16.40  44039200      15.89
2014-01-15  16.37  16.73  16.35  16.70  64118200      16.18
2014-01-16  16.67  16.76  16.56  16.73  38410800      16.21
2014-01-17  16.78  16.78  16.45  16.52  37152100      16.00
2014-01-21  16.64  16.68  16.36  16.41  35597200      15.90
2014-01-22  16.44  16.62  16.37  16.55  28741900      16.03
2014-01-23  16.49  16.53  16.31  16.43  37860800      15.92
2014-01-24  16.19  16.21  15.78  15.83  66023500      15.33
2014-01-27  15.90  15.91  15.52  15.71  51218700      15.22
2014-01-28  15.97  16.01  15.51  15.72  57677500      15.23
2014-01-29  15.48  15.53  15.20  15.26  52241500      14.90
2014-01-30  15.43  15.45  15.18  15.25  32654100      14.89
2014-01-31  15.09  15.10  14.90  14.96  64132600      14.61
>>> features = data.featurize(eq_data, 3)
>>> features
               -2     -1      0
Date

2014-01-06  14.96  15.02  15.09
2014-01-07  15.02  15.09   14.9
2014-01-08  15.09   14.9  15.05
2014-01-09   14.9  15.05  15.34
2014-01-10  15.05  15.34  15.57
2014-01-13  15.34  15.57  15.61
2014-01-14  15.57  15.61  15.89
2014-01-15  15.61  15.89  16.18
2014-01-16  15.89  16.18  16.21
2014-01-17  16.18  16.21     16
2014-01-21  16.21     16   15.9
2014-01-22     16   15.9  16.03
2014-01-23   15.9  16.03  15.92
2014-01-24  16.03  15.92  15.33
2014-01-27  15.92  15.33  15.22
2014-01-28  15.33  15.22  15.23
2014-01-29  15.22  15.23   14.9
2014-01-30  15.23   14.9  14.89
2014-01-31   14.9  14.89  14.61`

So each row of features is a series of 3 (`n_sessions`) successive values from the 'Adj Close' column of the `features` DataFrame.

====================

Improved version based on Primer's answer below:

`def featurize(equity_data, n_sessions, column='Adj Close'):
    """ 
    Generate a raw (unnormalized) feature set from the input data.
    The value at column on the given date is taken
    as a feature, and each row contains values for n_sessions
    >>> timeit.timeit('data.featurize(data.get("ge", dt.date(1960, 1, 1), 
            dt.date(2014, 12, 31)), 256)', setup=s, number=1)
    1.6771750450134277
    """
    features = pd.DataFrame(index=equity_data.index[(n_sessions - 1):],
            columns=map(str, range((-n_sessions + 1), 1)), dtype='float64')
    values = equity_data[column].values
    for i in range(n_sessions - 1): 
        features.iloc[:, i] = values[i:(-n_sessions + i + 1)] 
    features.iloc[:, n_sessions - 1] = values[(n_sessions - 1):]
    return features`

Comment: Post some example example input and desired output. It's really difficult to guess at what you're trying to accomplish otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `shift` is your friend here and something like this will do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'adj close': np.random.random(10) + 15},index=pd.date_range(start='2014-01-02', periods=10, freq='B'))
df.index.name = 'date'
df

                adj close
date                 
2014-01-02     15.650
2014-01-03     15.775
2014-01-06     15.750
2014-01-07     15.464
2014-01-08     15.966
2014-01-09     15.475
2014-01-10     15.164
2014-01-13     15.281
2014-01-14     15.568
2014-01-15     15.648

features = pd.DataFrame(data=df['adj close'], index=df.index)
features.columns = ['0']
features['-1'] = df['adj close'].shift()
features['-2'] = df['adj close'].shift(2)
features.dropna(inplace=True)
features

                 0      -1      -2
date                              
2014-01-06  15.750  15.775  15.650
2014-01-07  15.464  15.750  15.775
2014-01-08  15.966  15.464  15.750
2014-01-09  15.475  15.966  15.464
2014-01-10  15.164  15.475  15.966
2014-01-13  15.281  15.164  15.475
2014-01-14  15.568  15.281  15.164
2014-01-15  15.648  15.568  15.281
```

Comment: If it's going to have to be a loop, I definitely like doing it by column. I would think it would perform a bit better if one just sliced the column appropriately and saved the `dropna()` step.

Comment: Thanks, Primer, that was an amazing improvement! The whole process went from sitting around long enough to decide to press Ctrl+C to 1.7 seconds including data retrieval. Above is now my 'final' code, including a benchmark in the comment.